# Getting a clang error when compiling a simple C program using GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I just write a simple C program as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  return argc; 
}
```

However, when I compile and link the program, I encounter a Clang error. What's up with the setting or gcc?

```
LB:test liangbin$ gcc ./src/test_main.c -o ./obj/test_main.o
LB:test liangbin$ gcc ./obj/test_main.o -o ./bin/test_main
ld: can't link with a main executable file './obj/test_main.o' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*
```

Comment: What is your `gcc` command?

Comment: gcc ./src/test_main.c -o ./obj/test_main.o
gcc ./obj/test_main.o -o ./bin/test_main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you instructed `gcc` to put the output of the compilation in `./obj/test_main.o`, you did not tell it to make an object file rather than an executable file. By default, when given a source file, `gcc` both compiles and links it. As a result, `./obj/test_main.o` is an executable file, and the second command complains that it was given an executable rather than an object file.

You can fix this by changing the first command to:

```
gcc ./src/test_main.c -c -o ./obj/test_main.o
```

The `-c` switch instructs `gcc` to compile only, not to link.

Comment: yeah, the -c switch is the key to the problem. thanks.